# Is leaving a procedure with a return statement a bad thing?

Tags: function, return

I sometimes have colleagues frowning about using the `return` statement to leave a routine (before the end) because it looks like a kind of hidden goto and all gotos are evil. I neither share the thought about a goto being bad no matter how used nor can I really see why using `return` like this is so bad.

The question is relatively language independent. I currently program in PL/SQL and Objective-C so I give examples in this languages.

Objective-C

```
-(void)finishedLoading:(NSString*)result success:(BOOL)success 
{
    NSLog(@"delegate method finished loading invoked");   
    if (!success) {
        self.status.text = @"Failed to load file.";
        return; // IS THIS BAD??
    }

    self.status.text = @"File loaded.";

    // do more stuff here with result string
}
```

PL/SQL

```
PROCEDURE example(i_parameter pls_integer)
AS
BEGIN
   IF i_parameter IS NULL THEN
      RETURN; -- is this bad??
   END IF;

   -- do more stuff here

END example;
```

The examples are really only examples and maybe they can be criticized as they are, but I rather would like to know why the `return` should not be done. The only alternative that I see is to have a routine wide embracing if statement with potentially nested ifs making it hard to read but some people prefer that and I never figured out why.

Comment: what?!? no way, if there is a valid reason for the function to terminate (can't perform it's job, has located the thing searching for, etc), then it's more than valid, it's the proper thing to do IMO.

Comment: This question exists over on [Programmers.SE]: [Where did the notion of “one return only” come from?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/118703/), [Best practice in setting return value (use else or?)](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/87965/), where it's probably, as a "whiteboard" question, a better fit. Indeed, there are at least two deleted SO instances: [Should a function have only one return statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36707/), [Why should methods have a single entry and exit points?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1701686/), suggesting it might be too subjective for SO.

Comment: Although here's an extant version of it on SO: [Is it better to wrap code into an 'IF' statement, or is it better to 'short circuit' the function and return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051959/)

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Thanks for pointing to answers already existing. I overlooked the one in SO and apparently this is a question already answered on Programmers which I never look into. Actually I was not much aware of its existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's fine. In fact, I try to do all my validation at the top, either throwing or returning as necessary before the 'meat' of the method. Keeps things simpler with fewer nested-if/else's, etc. Also easier to unit-test with fewer code-paths to cover.

Answer (score 1):

Return only on exit of the procedure/function are a facet of Dijkstra's structured programming theory:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming

(see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_To_Statement_Considered_Harmful)

Theoretically, structured programming leads to easier to read code, and fewer bugs.  Check it out.